# What's the word for someone who loves two entities, like bilingual is one who knows two languages?

Tags: word-request

I saw the movie [Isle of Dogs (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5104604/) yesterday. The narrative described a kingdom of cat-loving humans waging war against the dog kingdom.<sup>1</sup> Later, some characters spoke only Japanese without subtitles or interpreters. Since I understand some Japanese, I got some [Bilingual Bonus](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BilingualBonus) (warning: tvtropes). In real life, I am not a 
"cat-person" or a "dog-person", but a "both"-person.

So, all of this got me into world building mode. I started writing a story involving *three* kingdoms, the cat-lovers, the dog-lovers, and the "both"-lovers. This is where my question comes:

**What's the word to describe a person who loves two entities?**

I would like to form a sentence like below:

> The cat-loving kingdom and the dog-loving kingdom have been at war for centuries, with the **bi<what?>** kingdom acting as the peacemaker to prevent a catastrophe.

so that it reads similar to:

> The English kingdom and the French kingdom have been at war for centuries, with the bilingual kingdom acting as the peacemaker to prevent a catastrophe.

Obviously, I don't want to go with "bi-lover" (or similar) due to certain connotations.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is from one of the earliest scenes and not particularly relevant to the plot, so not a spoiler.

Comment: I don't know if you'll get a good word for this or not, but, if not, you could always go with: _The cat-loving kingdom and the dog-loving kingdom have been at war for centuries, with the **lovers of both** acting as peacemakers._

Comment: I suppose **quadrupedophile** is out for similar reasons.

Comment: Note: I don't "love" any kingdom, it is part of the story I am writing. The third kingdom consists of people who love two entities, the entities being in this case, cats and dogs. It could also be chocolate and vanilla flavour, or cars and motorbikes, or red and blue colours, or apples and oranges.

Comment: Another prefix meaning "two" is **di-**. But again, **dizoophilic** is probably out.

Comment: Not sure it addresses your question, but how about "with *a neutral kingdom* acting as the peacemaker"? A Switzerland of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get too hung up on using the word "kingdom" There is no specific word in English so just describe:

> ... with lovers of both acting as peacemakers
>
> ... with neutrals acting as peacemakers

Answer (score -1):

The closest I can think of (which may not satisfy your specific requirement) is "the **egalitarian** kingdom."

From [**egalitarianism**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egalitarian):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : a belief in human equality especially with respect to social, political, and economic affairs
>   **2** : a social philosophy advocating the removal of inequalities among people

Of course, replace *people* or *humans* with *animals* . . .

Comment: If we use that word for animals, perhaps we should spell it _eaglelitarianism_....

Comment: Or   **pollyamory** if you prefer birds that can carry on a conversation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Toucan play at that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to invent the kingdom's name, it has to be easy to pronounce and it should contain references to both animals. So how about combing the words **feline** and **hund**? *[Feline](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feline)* refers to all members of the cat family while *[hund](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog#Etymology)* is an Old English word for *dog*

### Felizerhund

(inspired by Switzerland)

Obviously, a kingdom that loves cats should be called *Catland*, while a dog-loving kingdom could be called *Hundia* or *Houndlia*

Answer (score -1):

Cats and dogs are different species. So, in the spirit of bilingual (and bisexual), you could call lovers of both species "bispecials".

I thought this would be an invented word but then I found this word has already been used as a label in a similar context of [two species](http://www.cesam.ua.pt/index.php?menu=95&language=eng&tabela=projectosdetail&projectid=940).